# Golang's base64 implementation

Tags: go, base64

Recently, I have been looking to the golang's base64 implementation.

Can someone explain the purpose of **buf** in the encoder struct and the usage in the **Write** function ?

```
type encoder struct {
    err  error
    enc  *Encoding
    w    io.Writer
    buf  [3]byte    // buffered data waiting to be encoded
    nbuf int        // number of bytes in buf
    out  [1024]byte // output buffer
}
```

Here is the full implementation:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#NewEncoder

Tanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes each byte (8-bits) of input into 6-bits of output. To round this out into integral byte units - for every 3 bytes of input will produce 4 bytes of `base64` output.

Thus when encoding a stream of bytes, maintaining state from previous byte encodings is required i.e. a 3-byte buffer.

So, what happens if the input stream length is not a multiple of 3? When the stream ends, any remaining partial bytes in the buffer (i.e. 1 or 2 bytes) will be padded with one or two `=` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the example of Base64 binary-to-text encoding in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

[image: Base64 encode example]

To limit the use of resulting characters into using [the 64 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) (excluding padding `=`), Base64 encode opted to only represent 6 bits per result character.

3 bytes (24 bits) of binary data can be represents as 4 (24 bits / 6 bits = 4) encoding characters, which is the minimal number of binary data to fully use up every bits in the allocated encoding character. For this, you'd need to group 3 bytes and encode them together.

That's why they have a 3 bytes buffer for encoding a given byte stream. You won't be writing anything unless you have the buffer filled up or you reached the end of the stream.